# How to initialize an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to initialize an object in javascript..

My code is as follows:

```
var PageSlider = {

    sliders: [],

    addSlider: function(display, target, itemClass, width, height, itemsPerPage, defaultPage){
        var slideConfig = {
                display : display,
                target : target
        };
        var slider = this.createSlider(slideConfig);
        slider.initSlider();
        this.sliders.push(slider);

    },

    copy : function(obj) {
        if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
        var copy = obj.constructor();
        for (var attr in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
        }
        return copy;
    },

    getInstance : function(){
        var copy = PageSlider.copy(PageSlider);
        this.sliders.length = 0;
        return copy;
    }

}
```

Using the getInstance() method just copy the object.
What i need to do is to get the instance of the object.

Help please. Thank you.

Comment: The method `createSlider` - is this supposed to be a function on PageSlider, or is it a function on the object that's creating PageSlider?

Comment: yes. that's correct.  i need to make an instance of an object because i'm going to use it three times in one page. The problem is object is not being initialized

Comment: just use the word "new" as in: var slider = new PageSlider();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend prototyping, such as the following

```
var PageSlider = function() {
    this.sliders = [];
}

PageSlider.prototype.addSlider = function(display, target, itemClass, width, height, itemsPerPage, defaultPage){
    var slideConfig = {
            display : display,
            target : target
    };
    var slider = this.createSlider(slideConfig);
    slider.initSlider();
    this.sliders.push(slider);

}

slider = new PageSlider();
```

Answer (score 2):

PageSlider *is* an object already. So to get an instance outside of it, just use its name, like this:

```
var giveMeAnInstanceOfPageSlider = PageSlider;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way since PageSlider is already an object

var pageSlider = PageSlider

Answer (score 1):

How about `var pageSlider = PageSlider`. `PageSlider` is already an object.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the code is that `getInstance` will copy the object `PageSlider`, in effect initializing a new, empty object using the values of the existing `PageSlider` object — equivalent to getting an instance of the object.

This code is kind of strange as it blurs the line between "classes" and objects in JavaScript (kind of similar to what the programming language Io does), and more true to the notion of object prototypes.